# USB External Hard Drive with Windows 7 crashes

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I have a USB external hard drive with Windows 7, but, when I get to the OS itself, the computer crashes with code stop code 0x0000007B. Is there a way to fix it? I have tried doing stuff like restarting, chkdsk, last known good config, but nothing works. I used windows easy install, and it requires me to restart the computer so I can finish the installation. After that, I get the BSOD.

Comment: "with Windows 7": made with all drivers for you PC? Installation media? Your question is murky...

Comment: Do you mean that you have Windows 7 installed on an external drive? If so, did it work at some point before?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question, as it is, it is unclear to me what you're doing and trying to accomplish. Are you installing Windows? What are you chkdsk-ing? Etc. Do not reply with a comment, edit the question.

Comment: Windows is NOT to be installed in external drives.

Answer (score 0):

The difficult is your windows probably doesn't have the correct drivers for your USB port(s).

You need to get the drivers from the whom ever made the computer and/or motherboard.

Windows needs an INF file.
You need to extract the download files far enough so the *.INF file is visible.

During the windows install process you can add a driver, and add the driver you just download.

It might be that your USB ports are not directly part of the chipset and controlled indirectly by a controller from another company like ASMEDIA.

You might be able to boot by connecting it at least temporarily to a USB 2 port as they are more likely to be part of the chipset and not a separate controller.  Then you can add the correct drivers.

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is Windows 7 MUST be installed on an internal disk. Windows 7 doesn't treat an external SSD as RAID. Windows 10 does.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).